# How can I disable the action bar when text is selected in a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-dialogfragment

I'm working on an ICS (4.0.3) tablet app where we're using `DialogFrament` extensively. When the user does a long press inside a text editor in a dialog fragment I need to prevent the copy/paste action bar from appearing at the top of the screen. Fortunately we have our own base class extending `DialogFragment` (call it `MyOrgDialogFragment`) that all our dialog fragments are based on, so I can modify that if required.

My first attempt has involved overriding `OnCreateDialog()` in `MyOrgDialogFragment`, then overriding `onWindowStartingActionMode()` inside that, i.e.:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return new Dialog(getActivity()) {
        @Override
        public ActionMode onWindowStartingActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback)
        {
            return new ActionMode()
            {
                // [ All overrides empty ]
            }
        }
    };
}
```

This nearly works: it prevents the action bar from appearing, and the selection handles still appear when I long-press in an edit field (which is fine), but the selection handles aren't dismissed correctly when I move focus onto another edit field. I end up with "zombie" selection handles hovering over each edit field I've made a selection in.

Can anyone point me towards a better solution?

Comment: What interaction do you want to have with the EditText when long clicking it? Or you just want to block the ActionMode?

Comment: I just want to block the ActionMode: I'm not replacing it with any custom action.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback%28android.view.ActionMode.Callback%29) method that can be used on a `TextView`/`EditText`. If you use an empty `ActionMode.Callback` like this:

```
private ActionMode.Callback mModeCallback = new Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    };
```

the selection `ActionMode` will be blocked(with no selection handlers remaining when switching fields, in fact they will not appear at all).

Comment: @prateek I don't think so, there isn't a method to set a custom ActionMode.

Comment: Actualy I can customize the contextual action bar with Edittext on a long click but this isn't working for the selected text inside webview , do you have any workaround for this ?

Comment: @prateek I can't recommend something for that.

Comment: Yes, it removes action mode but it also affects text selection functionality. Not working perfectly.