# How to completely disable contextual action bar in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

There isn't any toolbar but showing contextual action bar when text selection below api v23, following codes not working to disable/remove. How to disable/remove completely?

[image]

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_book);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION 
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().removeAllTabs();
        getSupportActionBar().setShowHideAnimationEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getSupportActionBar().collapseActionView();
        getSupportActionBar().closeOptionsMenu();
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);
    }
}
```

My App Theme:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    ...
</style>
```

**Edit:**

Opening a special menu fragmen when long clicked my TextView with CustomSelectionActionModeCallback, and I've to return true the onCreateActionMode method because of to avoid selection cancellation during the selection, in this way (returning true) the event is prevented from going down but the action bar is opening api level 23 and down.

```
mTextViewItem.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        ...
        showMyMenuFragment();
        ...
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        return false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using a different Toolbar with a theme with no actionbar?

Comment: I've tried all of them, it's currently @style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629641/how-can-i-disable-the-action-bar-when-text-is-selected-in-a-dialogfragment?

Comment: @ATES your Activity extends AppCompatActivity or Activity?

Comment: @ATES if your activity extends Activty, then you need to do ```getActionBar().hide();```

Comment: extends AppCompatActivity.

Comment: @ATES, can you paste your styles.xml and the activity_read_book.xml ? Which device/emulator are you running your code on (model, API)?

Comment: My app supporting api21+ I've no android 5.0 device so trying it on android studio Pixel 3  google api21 virtual device and the codes you wanted:  [link](http://www.github.com/AliAtes/TestTools/blob/master/codes.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the `.NoActionBar` theme and set the `windowActionBar` attribute to `false`.

Beginning with the API level 21 action bar may be represented with any toolbar widget, within the application layout. An application may choose to designate a Toolbar as the action bar for an Activity using the `setSupportActionBar()` method.

Comment: thanks for reply, edited question for more details.